# Custom Field Type in 2013 Not Respecting Header Template

Tags: xslt, custom-field-types

I have a custom field type with a fldtypes_xxx.xsl template that we have carried forward from a 2010 solution into a 2013 solution.  The Number_body template we are using works just fine.  However, I cannot get the header template to work.

For the FieldRef I have tried matching the ID, FieldType, Type, Name, StaticName, etc.  Nothing seems to be able to get it to use the header template.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Considering the new CSR technique, which from experience i found quite easy to implement, would it be something you could consider?

Comment: So, in this context we are trying to make it so our current 2010 instances of these fields can be upgraded successfully when migrating to 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all of my testing, it appears that the current version of SharePoint 2013 does not process the header XSLT templates for custom fields.  It is possible this will change in a future update to 2013, but I doubt it.

So, the answer to my own question is that I have to use a different method for accomplishing what I needed to accomplish in the header template.  In this case, it was adding JavaScript for the rendering of the fields.  So, rather than use the XSLT template for this, I added code in an AdditionalPageHead delegate control that is part of the same feature that adds the custom field.  In this control, it checks to see if the SPContext.Current.List.Fields collection contains the field and then add the scripts to the page.